# How to write ng repeat for below Json Data?

Tags: angularjs

My data is coming as below from service. I have tried key, value but its not working.
I want to display all Product_Groups using ng-repeat in a dropdown.
I am using

```
ng-repeat="value.Product_Group for (key, value) in pgroup track by $index"
```

[image: My data is coming like this in console]

Comment: are u using select for the dropdown? then use `ng-options`

Comment: try <ng-repeat ="p in pgroup"> {{p.product_name}}

Comment: That is not correct syntax for `ng-repeat`. You are confusing it with the [ng-options directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions). Also see [AngularJS select directive API Reference (Choosing between `ngRepeat` and `ngOptions`)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#choosing-between-ngrepeat-and-ngoptions-)

Comment: Why don't you just read the documentation of ng-repeat to know what the syntax is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

```
  <div ng-repeat="item in pgroup track by $index">
    {{item.Product_Group}}
  </div>
```

**instead of**

```
ng-repeat="value.Product_Group for (key, value) in pgroup track by $index"
```

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.pgroup = [
     {Product_Group: "TrueBeam"},
     {Product_Group: "TrueBeam1"},
     {Product_Group: "TrueBeam2"}
    ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in pgroup track by $index">
    {{item.Product_Group}}
  </div>
</div>
```